# How to set an absolute position on a relative element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, offset

After some simplifications, the problem is I don't know how to set an image over another one when user clicks over the first one. It's more easy to see this in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/navi2000/T7czp/199/).

What's the problem? I believe the problem is the "relative" *div#problem* element. If you remove the "*position: relative*" from the CSS everything works fine, BUT I need the relative here.

Also, I've noted that if I change the "pin container" to the alternative one (directly pending from *HTML* tag) everything works fine, BUT I need the "pin container" inside the *relative DIV*.

What's the real problem? I supposed that `.offset()` will give me the position *relative to the document* as stated in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and `.offset(coordinates)` will do the same.

**NOTE**: The idea is the black box should appear in the same coordinates than the big image, but it appears misplaced.

**NOTE2**: I don't know if that's the problem, but I'm working on an Ubuntu Linux with Chrome and Firefox. Both browsers show the black box misplaced.

**NOTE3**: The goal is to take the coordinates of the big image and set a small box on the same position using an `absolute` positioning. No tricks like setting the same `margin` as the big image to the black box, sorry.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you want to have happen .. when I click the image a black square appears over it.  Is it supposed to appear in a particular spot?

Comment: Color me confused too. You are taking the `offset` of the parent `img` and applying it to the black box you are adding. It's working as I'd expect it to, but I doubt that's what you wanted to do. Are you trying to put the box where the mouse was clicked?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Sorry, the black box SHOULD appear just in the same offset than the big image, but it appears displaced some pixels down and right

Comment: @MattBurland: No, the box should appear in the left-upper corner of the big image, but instead, at least in the browsers I'm trying appears misplaced. I'm working on Linux: Chrome and Firefox gives the same result.

Comment: It's giving the same result because it's doing what it's supposed to.  Perhaps you're confusing `.offset` with `.position`?

Answer (score 2):

`.offset()` find the position of an element in relation to the document. You seem to want to use `.position()` to find the location inside the `relative` container.

See http://jsfiddle.net/T7czp/200/

You also need to apply the margin that the original image has and also apply the new dimensions with `.css()`

Answer (score 1):

`.offset()` returns the element's position relative to *the whole document*.  What you want is to get the position relative to *the offset parent* (`#inner` in this case).  That's what `.position()` is for.

```
$("img").click(function () {
    var offset = $(this).position(); // not offset!
    var $pin = $('<img>')
            .addClass('pin')
            .attr('src', "http://208.86.154.173/shared/images/black_box.png")
            .css({top: offset.top, left: offset.left}); //.offset() works, but shouldn't
    $("#pins").append($pin);
});​
```

Add a margin of 5px to the pin (the same margin that's on the original image), and the pin appears exactly at the top left corner of the image.